# Which is the official site to download the NXT (nxtcoin) wallet app?

Tags: wallet, nxt

Where is the official site to download the NXT wallet app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no the official site.**

You can download NRS (Nxt Reference Software) by following links from https://nxtforum.org/nrs-releases/. If you trust Jean-Luc then just check the file checksum. If you don't then analyze the source code and compile it yourself.

Comment: http://nxt.org/ looks pretty "official". Is there something unofficial about it? Should it be trusted to offer client app downloads?

Comment: It should not be trusted. I don't say that the person who runs it is not trusted, you should assume that a hacker got access to the site. The same is applied to ANY other website.

Comment: Well, yes, for maximum paranoia one need not trust anything. However, it seems that http://nxt.org seems like a pretty reasonable place to start and it's unclear to me why you said there was no official site.

Comment: Look at the definition of "official" and you will get why I said that there was no an official site: "An official is someone who holds an office (function or mandate, regardless whether it carries an actual working space with it) in an organization or government and participates in the exercise of authority (either his own or that of his superior and/or employer, public or legally private)."